# How can have font size less than 10pt in documentstyle LaTeX 2.09

Tags: fontsize, latex-2.09

I have a old file with `LaTeX 2.09` and `miktex 2`.

(I work in new latex. but They asked me to do it in his older `latex 2.09`. this file was writed in localised latex version in my country.)

I want to have font smaller `10pt` in `documentstyle`.

I read this site and in other sites. but i could not find solution for `latex 2.09`.

Please help me. Very thanks. best regards

Comment: If you are already changing a font size, does it matter if you use different LaTeX implementation altogether?

Comment: LaTeX 2.09 is very much out of date, so I cannot guarantee that this solution will work. It depends on what kind of styles you use. Better is to convert to the current LaTeX. But taking this into account you can try `\documentstyle[9pt]{extarticle}` (or `extreport` or `extbook`).

Comment: do you really want to use latex2.09 (the sources of which are still available but no longer distributed or built by default in tex distributions) or are you planning to use latex2e in 2.09 compatibility mode (in which case you may as well just use normal latex2e syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to put some work into the document anyway, so consider migration to the current LaTeX2e as an option.

It is not too difficult to take an old LaTeX2.09 documentstyle (and the files it includes) and modify them for 9pt. I think it has been done in the past, and a search in the dark corners of CTAN provides this page http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/misc featuring 9pt.sty for download.

Good luck in getting it working!